# Program not giving expected output

Tags: java

When I run,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   float num = 145/156;
   System.out.println(num);
}
```

I get output 0.0, but expected output is 0.92948717.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
  float num = (float)145/156;
  System.out.println(num);
}
```

As, `145/156` is `int/int`, so result is 0, type casted to float i.e 0.0

Comment: Your `145.0` solution is invalid. In Java floating point values are `double` by default, a cast would be necassary for `145.0` to become a `float`.

Answer (score 5):

Division of an integer to an integer **results an integer.**
So you are getting 0 because the data is getting truncated.

You need to type cast this to float

```
float num = (float)145/156;
```

Answer (score 2):

`145/156` is `0.something`, but because default numbers are coded as `int` in Java, you'll loose what's after `0` because the result will be truncated.

You should cast one of the sides (The other will be implicitly cast).

Answer (score 1):

145 and 146 literals are integer and / is integer division.

try to use just 145f (the f denote float) to force the decimal division.

Answer (score 1):

Why has no-one mentioned the shorter alternative?

```
float num = 145f/156;
```

Answer (score 0):

cast `145/156` to float like this   `float num = (float)145/156;`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `cast` at least one of the operands to a float

```
float num = (float) 145 / 156;
```

or

```
float num = 145 / (float) 156;
```

Answer (score 0):

`145` and `156` are both of type `int`, thus the result is 'interpreted' as an integer (everything behind the dot is truncated, so 0.92948717 will become 0), and saved into a variable of type `float`, which is presented as `0.0`.

Cast at least one of both numbers to a float in order to signal the machine to handle the result as a float.

```
float num = (float) 145 / 156;
```

Alternatively, you can suffix the number with an `f` to signal the machine to 'interpret' the number as a float:

```
float num = 145f / 156;
```

Answer (score 0):

here what you are doing is like,

```
int a = 145;
int b = 156;
float num = a/b;
```

that's why you get point zero at the end.
So to get the expected output you must first cast it as follows

```
float num = (float) a/b;
```

Comment: No, this will print 0.0 too

Comment: @user2336315 sorry it was a typing mistake. now its edited correctly

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you have used are integers. Integer division in Java results in an integer. Apart from casting the first number to float to force a conversion and proper floating-point operation, like this:

```
float num = (float)145/156;
```

you can also write the expression like this:

```
float num = 145f/156;
```

This way, by adding `f` at the end, the number `145f` is interpreted as float.

Answer (score 0):

145 and 156 are both ints, make sure at least one has decimals.  Example:

```
float num = (145.0 / 156);
```